# DataTables Showing Duplicate Pagination And Search Controls

Tags: javascript, html, pagination, datatables

I am having issues with using a second DataTables object on a different page.  I have successfully created a DataTable that sits on a page within my Web App.  It all looks fine and functions correctly.  However, I then copied the exact code and pasted it onto a second page and although my DataTable populates correctly, I am getting a second instance of the Pagination and Search controls (as shown below).  I have read some information on destroying the table as a second instance can be detected, but I have even tried turning off the first DataTable that I created and it doesn't seem to matter.

[image: DataTables - Top]

[image: DataTables - Bottom]

Loading my DataTable is done through the $(document).ready call on both pages although I'm not sure if this is correct as I want to load various DataTables on the same page but within different tab controls.

My code looks like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function() {      
        var siteTickets = $('#ticketsTable').DataTable( {
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bServerSide": false,
            "bDestroy": true,
            "ajax":{
                url :"framework/get_tickets_by_site.php"
            },
            aoColumns: [
                        { mData: 'id', sClass: "dt-body-center" },
                        { mData: 'summary',
                            "render" : function(data, type, row, meta){
                                   return $('<a>')
                                      .attr('href', data)
                                      .text(data)
                                      .wrap('<div></div>')
                                      .parent()
                                      .html();
                            }
                        },
                        { mData: 'c_location', sClass: "dt-body-center",
                            "render" : function(data, type, row, meta){
                                       return $('<a>')
                                          .attr('href', data)
                                          .text(data)
                                          .wrap('<div></div>')
                                          .parent()
                                          .html();
                                }
                         },
                        { mData: 'priority', sClass: "dt-body-center" },
                        { mData: 'first_name', sClass: "dt-body-center" },
                        { mData: 'created_at' },
                        { mData: 'due_at' },
                        { mData: 'status', sClass: "dt-body-center" },
                        { mData: 'last_updated' }
                ],
            "fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {           
                switch( aData["priority"] ) {
                    case "1":
                        $("td:eq(3)", nRow).text( "High" );
                        break;
                    case "2":
                        $("td:eq(3)", nRow).text( "Medium" );
                        break;
                    case "3":
                        $("td:eq(3)", nRow).text( "Low" );
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }       
                return nRow;
            },
            "order": [[0, 'asc']],
            "lengthMenu": [[20, 50, 100, -1], [20, 50, 100, "All"]]
        } );

    } );
</script>
```

I have also tried using the `DataTables.Destroy()` command but nothing seems to do the trick.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Related to this? [stackoverflow.com/questions/13984698/datatables-showing-two-search-boxes-and-pagination-data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13984698/datatables-showing-two-search-boxes-and-pagination-data)

Comment: @markpsmith It kind of is related, however, that article mentioned that it was caused by another dataTable being detected on the same node.  Not only is my other dataTable on a completely different page (and not even getting loaded) but I have commented out the code for the first dataTable and I still get the same problem.  Also, the article mentioned that he had moved away from dataTables so there was no real 'confirmed' resolution.

Comment: Can you post any more code that would help? The HTML maybe?

Comment: please post the code of you html table

Answer (score 2):

There's a slight error in the DataTable instantiation. The correct way to instantiate DataTables is using the lowercase `selector.dataTable` like this:

`$('#ticketsTable').dataTable(...)`

The syntax `selector.DataTable()` is used for DataTable API calls e.g:

`$('#ticketsTable').DataTable().rows('.modified').invalidate().draw();`

Comment: Another scenario of getting Two Pagination and Two search boxes is that, if we load the datatable script reference twice, it will initialise twice.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly this solution may fix your issue,
Set data-turbolinks to false in the tables

```
<table id="myTable" data-turbolinks="false">
 /* Insert table content... */
</table>
```

If you are using the below code for creating datatable,

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#myTable').dataTable({ });
 })
</script>
```