# Datatables second pagination and search bar after inserting row using table.row()

Tags: datatables

I'm having a problem with the datatables plugin.

I have table within a modal, which I edit in the table itself.
However when I'm adding a new row via table.row() the pagination gets weird.

Somehow instead of updating the pagination a new one appears beneath the old one. The new one gets updated while the old one doesnt.
[double pagination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNSHC.png)

I have checked, the table is not declared again, but even if it were, "retrieve" is set to true so that's not it. If I knew where the problem came from, I'd be able to fix it but I have no clue. Any ideas?

Edit: I foud out that the problem is with deleting rows, not with adding them. Why exactly, I still don't know

Comment: Theres also a similar question, but Im not sure it's the same issue and it didnt get a solution [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33663311/datatables-showing-duplicate-pagination-and-search-controls)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some problems with Regex for my inputs and once I fixed those, everything worked just fine. So my guess would be that if an error is thrown, dataTables might be stopped while running, which in turn causes this behaviour. In actuality I have no clue, why this fixed the problem, but it did. If you have a similar problem, try eliminating all errors/uncaught exceptions, etc.
If anyone knows more, I'd be glad to find out about it